# Invalid parameter: redirect_uri - keycloak error

Tags: keycloak, redirect-uri

I am trying to set up redirect_uri for keycloak(v 18.0.0) redirection after login success and encountering this error when I try to sign in. Any leads on how to set up redirection uri would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It will be helpful if you add some code to your post

Comment: I want to redirect to my web application after login

Comment: Set the redirect_uri to the url of the application that the user should be redirect after successfully login

Comment: let's say i want to redirect to google.com, where do i put the url for google in my keycloak application?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not given any details, I am assuming that you have some web application running at say `http://localhost:8080/my-app`

Now, Login to the Keycloak Admin dashboard -> Click on Clients -> select client -> In Valid Redirect URI's, add `http://localhost:8080/my-app/*`

Comment: I am running my keycloak on production and I need it to redirect to a different hostname. Is there any workaround for this through the keycloak dashboard itself? (I have integrated my keycloak with Azure AD and I am trying to redirect it to google.com for now) Thanks!

Comment: Just tell us the application hostname from where the request is redirected to Keycloak
e.g. http://myweb.hostname.com